# Instagram API - search user

Tags: instagram, instagram-api, react-native-instagram-login

i am building a website where you can get services for your Instagram account, i want to create a Search box that when you put your user name (e.g. "@John") it returns your profile picture and asks you if that is the correct profile (without logging in to your Instagram account),
I've found a website that made that possible already, does any one know how?!

the website - https://app.get-notch.com/acquisition/instagram-username

thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you found something ?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this [resource](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api) that allows you to do that. See an implementation of it [here](https://github.com/yasinatesim/instagram-fullsize-picture) and test it [here](https://instagram-fullsize-picture.yasinatesim.vercel.app/).